# Statistical test / model to assess what category (IV) leads to highest mean (DV)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

What *statistical tests* and e.g. *regression models* or similar can be done **in R** to asses which category (=predictor/IV, variable is called **strategy** 5-level factor ,e.g., "extreme", "average", mixed", ...) performs best in terms of the average correct choice (=respone/DV, variable is called **hit_mean**, ranges from 0 to 1.

There are further IVs I need to include in a model which are numeric (**similarity_mean)** & a binary dummy variable (**p_shaped**).

As the categorical variable **strategy** cannot be turned into a numeric variable as it will lose its logic behind it, what can be done in terms of regression, etc.? *Sample size = 1690)*.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit a fractional logit model and calculate the average of predictions at each level of strategy, leaving the other variables as they are. You can then test a joint hypothesis that the biggest effect pairwise dominates each of the others.